# How to make wildfly localhost connection automatically into https?

Tags: https, wildfly

I need to test my web application with https protocoll at localhost. How could I configure the settings on wildfly to make `https://localhost:8443/myapp.html` works?

New:

I added this to my security-realm:

```
 <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
                <server-identities>  
                    <ssl protocol="TLS">  
                        <keystore path="my_keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="xxx"/>  
                    </ssl>  
                </server-identities>
            </security-realm>
```

The keystore: my_keystore.jks was generated with java keygen utility and it is in the folder of standalone.xml.

And I added this to my default-server:

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" />
```

But now I got an exception like this:

```
Failed to start service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.UndertowRealm.keystore: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.security_realm.UndertowRealm.keystore: JBAS015229: Unable to start service
    at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeystore.load(FileKeystore.java:155) [wildfly-domain-management-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeystoreService.start(FileKeystoreService.java:78) [wildfly-domain-management-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeystore.load(FileKeystore.java:114) [wildfly-domain-management-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    ... 6 more
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with keystore (the jks file). Are you sure it is in jks format, or did you create it as pks12. If so, just set keystore-type="pkcs12"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to add an http-listener to the undertow subsystem configuration and configure it propperly with a security realm.

I cannot check this right now but I think this is the correct way to do this. I will try to configure a server this way asap.

Thats how I've set it up once for a customer:

```
<security-realm name="SSLRealm">
  <server-identities>
    <ssl protocol="TLS">
      <keystore path="serverkeystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="secureworld" alias="servercert"/>
    </ssl>
  </server-identities>
  <authentication>
    <truststore path="servertruststore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="secureworld"/>
  </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

The undertow config:

```
<https-listener name="default-https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SSLRealm" verify-client="REQUESTED"/>
```

unfortunately I can't tell you anything more about this keystore format issue since I'm not very familiar with this topic.

Comment: You're right. I tried it just now but now I still have an exception. I just edited the question and you will see what is my new problem. Thanks:)

Comment: thanks! It works! Yep, I did something wrong with the keystore format. I generated a new keystore with the proper format and it works perfect!