# Wildfly 11 configure (enable) SSL certificate

Tags: java, configuration, ssl-certificate, ca, wildfly-11

I have purchased an SSL online and got the following files:

- mydomain.ca file
- mydomain.crt file
- mydomain.csr file
- mydomain.key file
- mydomain.pem file
- mydomain.pkcs file

I searched for about an hour for tutorials on how to configure SSL on ***Wildfly 11***.
But in every tutorial they are generating self-signed certificates (which is not helpful in my case).

They use a tool called "***keytool***" to create "***.keystore***" files.

How can I create a ***.keystore*** file using my purchased certificate files ?

And how can I properly set up my `standalone.xml` (I am using standalone mode) to enable SSL ?

**EDIT**

Finally managed to generate the .keystore:

*1. Generate PKS12 from PEM (contains key + certs)*

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mydmain.pem -out mydmain.pfx -passout pass:myPass
```

*2. Generate KEYSTORE*

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass somePass -destkeypass somePass -destkeystore mydmain.keystore -srckeystore mydmain.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass myPass
```

Comment: Try usind this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528617/how-to-make-wildfly-localhost-connection-automatically-into-https