# Enabling SSL in Wildfly 17: Browser is showing certificate is not valid

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, keytool, wildfly-17

I have a Wildfly 17 server running on Ubuntu 18.04 TLS and tried to enable SSL as described in the links below:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html

[How to make wildfly localhost connection automatically into https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528617/how-to-make-wildfly-localhost-connection-automatically-into-https)

https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-ssl-https-on-jboss-wildfly-application-server-fde6288a0f40

I have issued a CSR request, purchased a CA certificate based on this CSR Request, and installed the purchased certificate into my keystore named heimdi.jks, which I created upon generating the CSR request in the folder of wildfly

```
/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration
```

After creating an additional `security-realm` and enabling the `<https-listener` to use it in my `standalone.xml`, as described in the links above, I started my Wildfly and tried to access it via https on port 8443. In the address bar of the browser I got the the message that the site is not secure.  When I clicked on the certificate, the browser said: "Certificate is not valid" (see below)

[image]

In the certificate viewer of my browser I' ve got :

[image]

and also

[image]

My keystore contains three entries:

```
administrator@14980:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration$ sudo 

keytool -keystore heimdi.jks -list -v
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries
```

Now, the first entity is the server certificate I bought:

```
Alias name: server
Creation date: Jun 7, 2022
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=heimdi.at
Issuer: CN=RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1, O="DigiCert, Inc.", C=US
Serial number: 2cd552dea82c2a783fee69d6f160d78
Valid from: Wed Jun 01 02:00:00 CEST 2022 until: Fri Jun 02 01:59:59 CEST 2023
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: B9:D9:C6:E3:B9:41:0F:39:F7:63:FB:B7:5C:22:3C:39:66:E6:BA:C1
     SHA256: 64:4B:9B:FB:85:C2:EC:54:C2:1C:66:65:51:A9:3C:AB:33:C9:D3:F9:20:8B:F1:77:D9:B0:0F:02:D1:86:53:97
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
```

The second one is the certificate of the intermediate authority:

```
Certificate[2]:
Owner: CN=RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1, O="DigiCert, Inc.", C=US
Issuer: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Serial number: a059b25f54b3d8794cc6631477538a3
Valid from: Wed May 04 02:00:00 CEST 2022 until: Mon Nov 10 00:59:59 CET 2031
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: 68:F2:2B:1A:62:98:F7:DA:19:1E:61:49:ED:8D:E0:EF:FF:54:AD:8C
     SHA256: 92:A5:F5:15:AD:35:D3:A2:7C:49:0E:DB:13:5D:E7:04:4B:1E:39:9D:60:8A:C1:AB:E8:83:FC:82:FB:4B:16:BE
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 4096-bit RSA key
Version: 3
```

And the last one is the root CA certificate:

```
Certificate[3]:
Owner: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Issuer: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Serial number: 83be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a
Valid from: Fri Nov 10 01:00:00 CET 2006 until: Mon Nov 10 01:00:00 CET 2031
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: A8:98:5D:3A:65:E5:E5:C4:B2:D7:D6:6D:40:C6:DD:2F:B1:9C:54:36
     SHA256: 43:48:A0:E9:44:4C:78:CB:26:5E:05:8D:5E:89:44:B4:D8:4F:96:62:BD:26:DB:25:7F:89:34:A4:43:C7:01:61
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTPS browser never gets your privatekey. Yours is **showing a *self-signed* (dummy) *certificate*** created on May 25, which is apparently when you did `keytool -genkey[pair]`. That operation creates a privatekey *and* a dummy cert which is intended to be replaced when you get a real one; it is not the privatekey but is *stored in* the PrivateKey *entry*, which actually [contains both the privatekey *and* a certificate chain](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html).

You obtained a 'real' cert (from RapidSSL/Digicert), but **did not correctly replace the dummy one**. You need to do `keytool -importcert -keystore x -file y -alias z` where x is your keystore `heimdi.jks`, y is the file containing the server cert you got, and z is the alias *of the PrivateKey entry* which is `server`.

But *before* that you need to have the *chain* certs, plural, in your keystore. Your server cert is issued by an *intermediate* CA, `RapidSSL Global TLS RSA4096 SHA256 2022 CA1`, but the root cert you have is for `DigiCert Global Root CA` which you can see is different. You should have (RapidSSL/Digicert should have supplied you) a 'chain' or 'intermediate' certificate that links these by having subject (which keytool calls 'owner') equal to the former and issuer equal to the latter. Your list shows TrustedCert entries for `therootca` and `client`; the former matches the (published) Digicert root but you don't say what's in the latter and it doesn't match any publicly-logged intermediate, plus it doesn't normally make sense to have any kind of 'client' cert in an HTTPS server keystore.

If RapidSSL gave you a 'bundle' file, look at it with any text tool like `cat` or `more` or an editor; it probably contains more than one certificate, but if you used it in `keytool -import[cert]` that only read the *first* one. Split out any subsequent cert(s) and look at each individually (for example with `keytool -printcert -file f`) to find the intermediate, or alternatively try downloading [this logged one](https://crt.sh/?id=6670931363). Import it to a *different* alias -- maybe `themidca` -- before importing the server cert to the privatekey alias `server` as above.

PS: there is no "Linux 18.04". You probably mean *Ubuntu*, which identifies releases with the yy.mm format, and the releases in April of even-numbered years, like 18.04, are "LTS" (Long-Term Support) -- not TLS. But even "long-term" is only free for 5 years, which expires next spring for your system.

Comment: Thank you! I did everything according to your detailed prescriptions, but now my browser says "Certificate is not valid" (see above my edited question with updated images.) Please help!

Comment: My Chrome (on Windows, currently 102.0.5005.63) connects okay -- `https://heimdi.at:8443/` gets the Wildfly default page with no error, `https://heimdi.at:8443/heimdi/login/login.xhtml` gets the login page ditto but VERY slow (per DevTools.Network, 21 requests totalling 1.6MB in 6.3 min, which is less than I got back in the 1990s on voiceband dialup). Try other client system(s) or program(s). Your cert-viewer window doesn't show any error on the leaf/bottom cert; try clicking each of the higher certs (intermediate and root) and see if they say anything useful.

Comment: I also connect OK in Chrome under Windows (bit not under Linux), my initial request on Windows took 22 sec. I looked at the certificate chain, bit did not see any errors. However, subsequent request after loggin on went much faster. What should I specifically look for? Why is https (at least the initial request) so slow compared to http? I also looked in the server logs, but did not find any errors.